# Radio Input (Button) switch/toggle styling not Working on IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, radio-button, togglebutton

EDITED

Switch/Toggle Radio input button working on other browsers but not on IE.

> Forgot to mention that I'm editing an existing markup from an old
>   project. I hope to fix the issue from CSS side and resolve the issue without modifying the markup
>   (bellow) as much as possible cause it's globally used.

```
<div class="input-icon">
   <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="switch">
</div>
```

`Please check my codes` https://codepen.io/vrsotto/pen/qGpzeE

Comment: Can you please confirm that your code is working properly on other browsers? I test it with Chrome and Edge and your toggle button looks like this. https://i.postimg.cc/ncT66WWm/102.png If code is not correct than please try to post modified code.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT yes. the 1st screencap that I attached is from IE v11

Comment: I mean to say that your code is not working properly and not showing that toggle button properly in other browsers as you had posted above. so it is expected that you will get same kind of result for IE. I suggest you to post a code that can match with your above posted output. So that we can again try to make a test with IE to find the issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT sorry if my question is confusing. My only issue is on IE. On other browsers (like: FF and Chrome), my radio styling is work just fine.

Comment: Did you tested the above code? If not than please test it first. It is looking like disabled.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT yes. https://codepen.io/vrsotto/pen/qGpzeE

Comment: What code? I don't see any code. [mcve]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Try to make a test with code below may help you to fix the issue for Internet Explorer.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: limegreen;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px limegreen;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>



<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE 11:

[image]

Comment: Some CSS attributes which you had used in your code is not supported in IE for example: appearance. So you can try to compare your code with mine code and modify it with the help of my code may help to fix the issue.